# Mysql field type for md5 unique id

Tags: mysql, md5

I am creating a unique id and would like to know what field structure I should be using.  I am creating the id in php using md5 and uniqueid.

```
md5(uniqid($filename))
```

I have set the field in the database to varchar.  I wanted to know if this was correct and also if correct how many chacaters should it be set to.

Many thanks

Comment: Set a varchar of 32 as `md5()` generates a 32 bit length string.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran MD5 generates 128 bit values. Only in hexadecimal representation, i. e., 4 bits per byte, it’s 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MD5 returns 128 bit values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) which can be represented as a sequence of 32 hexadecimal characters, which is also the type of value PHP’s `md5` function returns. So `CHAR(32)` would fit perfectly.

You could also turn the value into binary, i. e., 8 bit per byte instead of 4 bit per byte. This can be done with PHP’s `md5` function by setting the second parameter *raw_output* to `true`. Or in MySQL using the [`UNHEX` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex). In that case `BINARY(16)` would suffice.